# Looking for a mount with 3D play to it

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motion, actuator

I'm building a lift bed in a van.  The basic idea is that each corner of the bed is mounted on a linear track actuator, bed goes up, bed goes down.

[image: bed lift on actuators]

I want to be able to control each actuator independently so that I can level the bed if parked on a slight incline.  The problem with this is that as the bed becomes un-level relative to the van the mounting points are going to need to be able to have some play to them.  Quick napkin math says that on a 10º incline, I'd need 1.3" of horizontal play on the long axis and 1" on the short (@20º it's 5"/3.6").

My initial idea is to just mount each corner in the middle of an "X" of 100lb springs, but there has to be a better solution!  Any ideas?

Comment: The easy solution would be three actuators. Three points make a plane, four points make it crooked.
If you *must* have four actuators, three of them would need to have ball joints at their bottom in addition to each having a joint at the point of contact with the bed frame.

Comment: use short chains to hang the corners of the bed

Comment: Don't forget that the actuators will no longer be totally vertical in this situation. At least 2 of them will need to be able to tilt at a slight angle.

Answer (score 0):

A ball and socket joint, like some suspension or steering joints.